# How to properly make animation/transition in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I want to smoothly resize a DIV with onClick event. But transition doesn't work. onClick just changes the style without animation.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.scss';

function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(-1)

  return (
    <div 
      className={clicked === -1 ? "app" : "app__clicked"} 
      onClick={() => setClicked(0)}>
        div clicked {clicked}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.scss

```
.app {
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 3s;

  &__clicked {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with SCSS.

Comment: I don't see a transition or animation anywhere in your scss

Comment: transition: width 3s;

Comment: It's not in your scss, so it doesn't count.

Comment: do not you see it in App.scss?
.app {
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 3s;

  &__clicked {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
  }
}

Comment: My bad. It's there, I'm just tired.

Comment: You need to set a width on .app like 100% or something other than auto. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-water-lyogy

Comment: thank you Mr. Bamford.. it works perfect.. and actually transition reference should be just in .app__clicked{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector#adding-suffixes), your SASS rules will result in two different css classes which you toggle between when assigning a `className` prop to your `div`.

The second class is `app__clicked` and it has no `transition` property which is why the transition doesn't work. It also doesn't work because, as indicated in the comments, you don't have an initial `width` on the `div`, so there is nothing to transition between. By moving the `transition` property to the `app_clicked` class and setting `width` to `100%` in the initial state, you will have a working example.

As an advice when doing transitions manually, use a base class which has the `transition` property set and then toggle the other state by means of other classes (or inline with `style`) to make sure that the element always has the `transition` property set. Like this:

```
<div className={ `app ${clicked === -1 ? "before" : "after"}`}>
    div clicked {clicked}
</div>
```

or

```
<div className={ "app" } style={{"width": clicked === -1 ? "100%" : "100px"}}>
    div clicked {clicked}
</div>
```

Finally, you might wanna have a look at [`react-transition-group`](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) where transitions with React components is shown. However, you might think that this brings nothing new to the table and that it is too verbose. But it's good to know about and it might have its use cases.

Here is a sandbox with all of the above examples and an example with the `CSSTransition` component from `react-transition-group`: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-gynd6)